# What's the grammatical construction of "its sense as..."?

Tags: grammar, to-infinitive

> row
>
> The word *row* has many different meanings, but we are interested in **its sense as a noun to mean** “a noisy dispute” and a verb to mean “to noisily argue.” *Row* can be used in this sense as in While my friends and I like to row about the best ninja turtle, in the end, we agree it is obviously Donatello. This sense of *row* is first recorded in the 1740s, but its origin is unknown.

[Source](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/ways-to-say/synonyms-for-argue/)

---

1. What's the grammatical construction of the bold part?
2. Does "**to**" mean roughly "which"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...we are interested in its sense as a noun to mean “a noisy dispute”

means "**we are interested in the sense where it functions as a noun and means 'a noisy dispute'**".

Grammatically "as a noun to mean..." is a prepositional phrase acting as a restrictive modifier of 'sense'.

It's a little unusual to see 'sense... to mean'. But it certainly should be interpreted as I wrote in boldface, above.   You can tell the meaning from context, and from the "feeling" of the preposition itself, and you will get a better understanding of prepositional intent as you become more proficient.

If it helps, the sense of the preposition "to" here is exactly as if the author had written:

"we are interested in its **use** as a noun to mean “a noisy dispute”"

... and this last sentence arguably is clearer and sounds more natural or familiar.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find some words function sometimes *as* verbs and sometimes *as* nouns ('swimming' is an example). Other words have many definitions and functions, some of which may be unrelated.

One of the words you are asking about, 'sense', has many meanings. The definition we are interested in here is "*one of the possible meanings of a word or phrase*".

Your example text is saying that "we" (the speaker and the audience) are just interested in one specific sense (meaning) of the word 'row'.

Comment: This doesn't address the question asked.  (ie.  neither (1), nor (2), above)

Comment: @BadZen Asking more than one question within a question is against the site rules. However, the OP has a fundamental misunderstanding of where the phrase begins and ends in the example. I've reframed it and answered it holistically.

Comment: I agree that (1) and (2) are not "different question" for the purpose of on-topic-ness.  You still don't address either - you don't describe the "grammatical construction of the bold part", and you talk about the meaning of "sense" instead of "to", contrary to what is asked.